# No authentication handler is configured for the scheme: idsrv

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

i'm fairy new to the .net core world and am trying to setup a identityServer. I followed the guide from https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html and managed to get the basics working. I now want to use .Net core Identity in combination with identityServer but it's giving an exception i don't know how to solve. The exception:

***No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: idsrv***

```
 Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.GrantsController.Index (IdentityServer) in 22.9784ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: idsrv
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<GetAuthenticateInfoAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

I've tried browsing github issues for simmilar issues and some people said it was related to the order IdentityServer and Identity are loaded. But in my case they should be correct?

My Startup.cs class:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            // Adds IdentityServer
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseIdentity();

            // Adds IdentityServer
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this exception? From an `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Comment: Added some more info about the exception. I'm using the quickstart GUI from identityServer4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `Configure()` method:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "idsrv", // Matches the name it's looking for in the exception
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to setup cookie middleware in Configure() method.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemeConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme,
        CookieName = $"{AuthenticationSchemeConstants.CookiePrefixName}.auth",
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
        AutomaticChallenge = false
    });

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemeConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
        AutomaticChallenge = false
    });

    app.UseIdentityServer();
```

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/signin_external_providers.html
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1058

Hope it helps

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I think this problem stems from the combination of Identity with IdentityServer? This is what i'm trying to do: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

Answer (score 0):

in `.NET core 2.0` *Provider*AuthenticationOptions class no longer defines `AuthenticationScheme` property.

> In 1.x, the AutomaticAuthenticate and AutomaticChallenge properties were intended to be set on a single authentication scheme
>
> In 2.0, these two properties have been removed as flags on the individual AuthenticationOptions instance and have moved into the base AuthenticationOptions class. The properties can be configured in the AddAuthentication method call within the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs:

`authenticationScheme` should be configured while invoking Use*Provider*Authentication method **inside ConfigureServices** method

```
services
   .AddAuthentication(opts =>{
       opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }) 
   .AddCookie("idsrv", opts =>
    {
        //AuthenticationScheme = "idsrv",
        //AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        //AutomaticChallenge = true
    })
```

Comment: "The properties can be configured in the AddAuthentication method call within the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs"

No they are not.